# If 404 error, redirect to pageNotFound and then redirect to home page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm creating a website using Node JS and if the user tries to go to a nonexistent page then I would like to redirect to a page that says "Page Not Found.. Redirecting to Home Page" and then after like 5 seconds, redirect to the index page. I have both html files for the index and the pageNotFound but I read that it's bad practice to redirect to multiple pages. I was wondering if anyone had a better idea of how to do this.

1. User enters nonexistent page
2. go to /pageNotFound
3. pause so user can read page
4. go to index page

This catches all leftover pages that the user tries to go to:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/pageNotFound');
});
```

The user is redirected to the pageNotFound.html

```
app.get("/pageNotFound", function(req, res) {
    res.render("pageNotFound");
});
```

Comment: You could do something like that by putting a `reload` statement into your 404 error page but many say it is not a good idea to remove control from the user by automatic reloads. Have you considered putting a link to the home page on your 404 error page? This way the user would remain in control. Another way would be to display the home page with an extra “not found” message the user could close.

Comment: see if this is helpful [Best practices to design a 404 error page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84856/best-practices-to-design-a-404-error-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *setTimeout* function on you pageNotFound and *window.location* to redirect to homePage after 5 sec.

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location="homePage"; }, 5000);
```

Comment: If you do not want to depend on JavaScript you can do this using a `meta` header: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=/home…">`